# Why is my array index out-of-bounds in this algorithm?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, algorithm

So I'm doing a little practice that is self-explanatory in the commented code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{

    public static int[,] GetPairs ( int [] arr ) 
    {
        // given an array arr of unique integers, returns all the pairs
        // e.g. GetPairs(new int [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }) would return
        // { {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {4, 5} }   

        int n = (arr.Length * (arr.Length - 1))/2; // number of pairs unique pairs in an array of unique ints
        if ( n < 1 ) return new int[0,2] {}; // if array is empty or length 1
        int[,] pairs = new int[n,2]; // array to store unique pairs
        // populate the pairs array:
        for ( int i = 0, j = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i ) 
        {
            for ( int k = i + 1; k < arr.Length; ++k )
            {
                pairs[j,0] = arr[i];
                pairs[j,1] = arr[k];
                ++j;
            }
        }
        return pairs;       
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        int [] OneThroughFour = new int [4] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        int [,] Pairs = GetPairs(OneThroughFour);
        for ( int i = 0; i < Pairs.Length; ++i )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}",Pairs[i,0],Pairs[i,1]);
        }

    }
}
```

and the error I'm getting is

> [System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the
>   array.]

in the loop

```
    for ( int i = 0; i < Pairs.Length; ++i )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}",Pairs[i,0],Pairs[i,1]);
    }
```

which doesn't make any sense to me. What is out-of-bounds? Surely not the `i`, for it is in the range `0`, `1`, ..., `Pairs.Length - 1`. Surely not the `0` or `1`, for those are valid indices.

Also, is it possible to do this better than `O(n^2)` and is there a way with .NET that is more compact and efficient?

Comment: `Pairs.Length` is not the length of the first dimension. It is the multiplication of the lengths of the two dimensions.

Comment: Try `for ( int i = 0; i <= Pairs.GetUpperBound (0); ++i )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For two dimensional arrays, the `Length` property returns the length of the first dimension multiplied by the length of the second dimension. In your case, this is equal to `2 * n`

What you want, as far as I can tell is to loop through the first dimension.

Use the [`GetUpperBound`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getupperbound(v=vs.110).aspx) method like this:

```
for (int i = Pairs.GetLowerBound(0); i <= Pairs.GetUpperBound(0); ++i)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Good spotting, Yacoub.

Comment: Thanks @QualityCatalyst

Comment: A bit inconsistent. Either use `i = GetLowerBound(0); i <= GetUpperBound(0); ...` or `i = 0; i < GetLength(0); ...`